# jQuery involving Bootstrap dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

I have these lines of code

```
<script src="dassets/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="dassets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="dassets/prettify/run_prettify.js"></script>
<link href="dassets/bootstrap-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="dassets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

 <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

The problem is that the Bootstrap dialog is not showing. When I remove the jquery-1.11.2.min.js below,the bootstrap dialog can be viewed but the collapse function in the webpage is not working anymore. And when I remove the jquery-1.10.2.min.js above the collapse function work but the Bootstrap dialog can't be seen
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load `jQuery` before the `dialog`.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="dassets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="dassets/prettify/run_prettify.js"></script>
<link href="dassets/bootstrap-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="dassets/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>


<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Why do you load 2 `jQuery` files?

Comment: i wasnt using bootstrap dialog before i integrated it today but i wasnt successful yet :)